# Why Multer destination is unused

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm, multer

I'm trying to save image from `request.data`. But I cant even test why it's not working.

Here is my code below. But I don't receive any errors, or console.log inside destination.

WebStorm IDE suggests that `destination` and `filename` properties are unused. But why?

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log(req, file)
        const dir = 'public/upload';
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            return fs.mkdir(dir, error => cb(error, dir));
        } else {
            return cb(null, dir);
        }
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/createCatalogProduct", upload.single('data.image'), catalogController.createCatalogProduct)
```

[image]